# Struggling to get ListView display within fragment alongside Tabs in Android 3.0

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

I have issues with fragments/listviews in Android. I have a tabbed activity, and one of the tabs has a listview embedded within a fragment. IT doesn't display. I used the android wizard to generate some of the boiler plate code. The 4 tabs display well. But the second tab that has a listview doesn't display at all. I have spent over a day now trying to find the cause, and unable to find root cause. Any pointers?

EmplyeeDetail has 4 tabs. One of the 2nd tab needs to have a log (notes) shown as a listview.

```
EmployeeDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    ......
    ......
    @Override
    ....protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emplyee_detail)
    ...
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the four
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    }

     public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if  (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__tab2_, container, false);
                return rootView;
    ......
    }
```

Now I have a pager

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }
```

Now the actual fragment looks somewhat like this

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {


public Tab2Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment and return it
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__tab2_, container, false);

    String[]  menuItems = {
            "list item 1",
            "list item2"
    };

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_log);


    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            menuItems
    );


    //use this adapter to draw on screen
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I see that in `PlaceholderFragment` the `onCreateView` returns the `rootview` as inflated tab2 layout which does not have the adapter set to the `ListView`. Is there any reason returning the `view` instead adding the fragment ?

Comment: May be my understanding is in-correct. The fragment "Tab2Fragment" has an onCreateView that has the listview array adapter set. See Tab2Fragment. code. Unless I am missing something.  Should I be doing something more in the "onCreateView" in the activity that contains these 4 tabs (i.e tab2 which is supposed to show the list). I though when you include a fragment, the onCreate always returns the rootview by inflating the layout file.

Comment: Something strange is going on, when I modify as suggested by you the code "else if  (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {" and set the adapter then the listview pops up in Tab2. But I already setup the fragment Tab2Fragment.java code with createview to have the adapter etc...why is that code not getting called?